# Check wordcount in until loop

Tags: bash

I want to continue my bash script only when my Docker container has 2 mentions of a string in the logs..I tried the following code but can't seem to re-count the variable (using eval), so it stays stuck:

```
number=`docker logs mysql 2>&1 | grep 'mysqld: ready for connections' | wc -l`

until [ "$number" -eq 2 ]; do
    sleep 2
    echo $number
    eval "$number"
done

echo Mysql started and rebooted, continue..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

```
number=0

until [ "$number" -eq 2 ]; do
    sleep 2
    number=`docker logs mysql 2>&1 | grep 'mysqld: ready for  connections' | wc -l`
done
```